# better way to judge model is null?

Tags: android, model

When I bind data in Adapter, I use Model to do this.

```
class ModelA{
    ModelB b;
    ......
    geters and setters
}

class ModelB{
    ModelC c;
    ......
    geters and setters
}

class ModelC{
    String name;
    ......
    geters and setters
}
```

when I  want to use name, I need to do this:

```
bindData(ModelA a) {
    String name = a.getModelB().getModelC().getName();
    mTextView.setText(name);
}
```

but model may be null,so I added this:

```
bindData(ModelA a) {
    if(a != null && a.getModelB() != null 
        && a.getModelC() != null 
        &&!TextUtils.isempty(a.getModelB().getModelC().getName())) {
    String name = a.getModelB().getModelC().getName();
    mTextView.setText(name);
    }
}
```

However I think use try catch may be easier,so I changed this:

```
bindData(ModelA a) {
    try{
        String name = a.getModelB().getModelC().getName();
        mTextView.setText(name);
    }catch (NullPointerException e) {
        ......
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to judge model is null? if not, "if" and "try catch" which is better?

Comment: I can't think of a nice way to handle your use case.  As a possible alternative, may I suggest not maintaining such a nested class structure in your code?  Do you really need a hierarchy of depth 3 here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, this is only a sample , but I even used more than 3 depth, and it is necessary, I can't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I checked if model is null in advance and I don't check variable from getter(). Because if it's null, we don't need to render views. (It's one of the reason why I want to move Java to Kotlin because I don't like checking NULL)

```
initViews() {
    // handle your default data for Views
}

renderViews(ModelA a) {
    ModelB modelB = a.getModelB;
    if (modelB == null {
        return;
    }

    // bind data of ModelB to Views

    ModelC modelC = modelB.getModelC();
    if (modelC == null) {
        return;
    }

    // bind data of ModelC to Views

    String name = modelC.getName();
    mTextView.setText(name);
}
```

Comment: If data is null, I need to bind a default, in this way I need to call times of method to bind default data in every if - block

Comment: @ngU In my case, I have two method for handling data such as initViews() and renderViews(). renderViews is for handling remote data. I think It's common issue for Android developers. I think you can check famous sample open-source projects.

Comment: I'd like to use `mTextView.text = a.modelB?.modelC?.name ?: return;`.

Comment: But that's Kotlin... :D